# How to diagnose wi-fi on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, lineageos, oneplus-6

I'm an Android enthusiast, as most of you, and I installed Lineage OS on my Oneplus 6 two months ago. Everything works fine but not Wi-Fi that randomly disconnects from my router. In the end of the day the connection is unusable, disconnecting and recovering every 30 seconds. The Wi-Fi only stabilizes after a reboot.

I have already discarded router and internet connection issues because other devices (including other non-lineage Android devices) works perfectly while I am suffering.

I'm looking for a way to diagnose and solve this issue. What are your recommendations? I would appreciate every tip!

Thanks!

Environment information:

- Oneplus 6 A6003 (enchilada)
- Lineage 18.1 (Android 11 - 20210921-nightly-enchilada)
- Router: Google Wi-Fi
- Country: Brazil (not spanish, portuguese!)
- other possible linked issues: bluetooth works fine with my headset, but has a similar issue on my car (only audio Android Auto on Ford media center)